Which template is actually for using pointer = typename _Ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::type; for different contidion?
The code below is seen at unique_ptr.h
template <typename _Tp, typename _Dp>
class __uniq_ptr_impl
{
    template <typename _Up, typename _Ep, typename = void>
    struct _Ptr
    {
      using type = _Up*;
    };

    template <typename _Up, typename _Ep>
    struct
    _Ptr<_Up, _Ep, __void_t<typename remove_reference<_Ep>::type::pointer>>
    {
      using type = typename remove_reference<_Ep>::type::pointer;
    };

public:
    using _DeleterConstraint = enable_if<
        __and_<__not_<is_pointer<_Dp>>,
        is_default_constructible<_Dp>>::value>;

    using pointer = typename _Ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::type; 
    
//omit code below ...

}

I want to know which template is actually for using pointer = typename _Ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::type; for different contidion(i.e. different types of _Up, _Ep).

It's using SFINEA to determine whether the deleter template argument type provides a fancy pointer type or not. If deleter provides a fancy pointer type, that will be used instead of T*.

@Red.Wave What's the said fancy pointer type?

Depends on the deleter. The deleter may decide that built-in raw pointer is not good enough for memory management, so it defines a replacement type.

This code from the standard library is an implementation of [unique.ptr.single.general] p3:

If the qualified-id remove_reference_t<D>​::​pointer is valid and denotes a type ([temp.deduct]), then unique_ptr<T, D>​::​pointer shall be a synonym for remove_reference_t<D>​::​pointer.
Otherwise unique_ptr<T, D>​::​pointer shall be a synonym for element_type*.

In this code, SFINAE in the partial specialization of _Ptr is used to determine whether typename remove_reference<_Ep>::type::pointer is a type. D in the standard wording is _Ep in this implementation.
If it is a type, pointer is taken from the deleter; otherwise the primary template defines type as _Up*, which makes pointer an element_type*.
See also How do we use void_t for SFINAE? for a more in-depth explanation of this technique.
See also about the type of raw pointer inside unique_ptr for why it is useful to have pointer be customizable instead of always using element_type*.

Thank you for the reply. I studied SFINAE sometime ago.  What confused me is the remove_reference<_Ep>::type::pointer expression. What's that?

It's the remove_reference_t<D>::pointer from the cited paragraph. C++11 didn't have that alias template, so you would have to write remove_reference<D>::type::pointer, but it's the same thing. It's just accessing the pointer alias which may be defined inside of the deleter.
